# Why doesn't sync guarantee that buffers are flushed?

Tags: io, synchronization, buffer

As far as I can see, the only use of `sync` is to ensure that there's no incomplete information, which is supposed to be safely written on disk but may actually be still only in a volatile buffer. However, `sync` *doesn't actually guarantee that at all* — it [merely *schedules* those buffers to be written](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/007908799/xsh/sync.html), but doesn't wait for that to complete.

What's the point of that? If you really want to ensure the system is safe for shutdown, then you most certainly would want it to wait for that to be complete. (Likewise if you want all buffers empty before you start something latency-critical.) OTOH, if you want a program to continue right now and don't want to wait for buffers to be flushed, then why bother with `sync` at all? The buffers would be flushed anyways at some point when needed for other data.

This behaviour seems to have lead to [some odd fairy tales about the need to `sync` multiple times](https://utcc.utoronto.ca/~cks/space/blog/unix/TheLegendOfSync).

Comment: Related: [Is there truth to the philosophy that you should sync; sync; sync; sync?](//unix.stackexchange.com/q/5260)